# Возникновение значения "Нет" при конвертации строки в вещественное число

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В датафрейме нужно конвертировать строки в числа:

```
for n in df_court.columns:
    if 'sum' in n:
        df_court[n] = df_court[n].str.replace('руб', '')
        df_court[n] = df_court[n].str.replace('млн', '00000')
        df_court[n] = df_court[n].str.replace('млрд', '00000000')
        df_court[n] = df_court[n].str.replace('Сумма неизвестна', "NaN")
        df_court[n].fillna('NaN', inplace=True)
        df_court[n] = df_court[n].str.replace(' ', '')
        df_court[n] = df_court[n].str.replace('.', ',')
        #df_court[n] = df_court[n].str.replace(',', '')
        df_court[n] = df_court[n].astype(np.float64)
```

Но если выполнить предпоследнюю строку, возникает странное значение "Нет", которое нельзя переименовать или конвертировать во float

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Нет'

а значения становятся такими

```
r_data_courtPractice_dashboard_blocks_0_sum NaN           6588
Нет            459
500            191
1000            95
1500            49
1000000         46
2000            44
1100000         38
1200000         30
1500000         24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том что у вас присутствует значение `Нет` вместо числа.

после всех замен избавьтесь от всех символов, кроме тех, которые представляют числа:

```
df_court[n] = df_court[n].str.replace(r'[^\d\.]', '')
# convert strings to numericals
df_court[n] = pd.to_numeric(df_court[n], errors='coerce')
```